# How to use custom controls on Mapbox MGLMapView

Tags: ios, uiview, touch, custom-controls, mapbox

I want to implement [KCFloatingActionButton](https://github.com/kciter/KCFloatingActionButton) (or something similar) on a Mapbox MGLMapView but can't get the button action to work. The button recognises the initial touch, the colour changes, but nothing else happens. I'm not sure if the map is stealing touches or has higher precedence somehow.

Inspecting the view hierarchy shows the UIButton and associated UIViews are above the map so I'm at a loss. I thought it might have been the use of views in the button as well as the actual UIButton object but I'm able to attach a gestureRecognizer to a simple UIView on the map no problem (except the map still registers drags and taps through the view). Also vanilla UIButton objects work fine.

EDIT: Just swapped view to MKMapView and button works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you learn something new everyday. Just wish it was yesterday.

Superview contain subviews. In my case the MGLMapView contains a KCFloatingActionButton (itself deriving from a UIView). Superviews have gesture recognizers attached. In my case the mapView has the usual taps and swipes normally associated with maps. Default behaviour is for those gestures to 'not' be blocked by subviews so the mere presence of the button doesn't stop the superview from recognising it's gesture.

By adopting the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate and implementing:

```
override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

I can selectively handle how my 'button' handles gestures deriving from the superview. As I read it UIButtons default to this behaviour for single taps but my UIView-based button doesn't.